# How to create a vertical carousel in boostrap 5 with the previous image fixed?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

I need of help in my vertical carousel project.

How to create a vertical carousel in bootstrap 5 with the previous image fixed?

I see here this slider: zara.com/jp/en/

I want to keep the previous image fixed while I scroll up or down through the current image.

I tried `position: fixed;` in the previous image to test, but not working.

```
html:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link href="./style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link
      rel="preload"
      href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/dummy/7.jpg"
      as="image"
    />
    <link
      rel="preload"
      href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/dummy/8.jpg"
      as="image"
    />
    <link
      rel="preload"
      href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/dummy/9.jpg"
      as="image"
    />
    <link
      rel="preload"
      href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/dummy/10.jpg"
      as="image"
    />
    <title>Bootstrap 5 Vertical Carousel Example</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="./images/bootstrap.ico" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="carousel-container justify-content-center">
      <div
        id="vertical-carousel"
        class="carousel slide"
        data-bs-ride="carousel"
        data-bs-interval="false"
        data-bs-wrap="false"
      >
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div
            class="carousel-item active"
            style="
              background-image: url(https://www.jqueryscript.net/dummy/7.jpg);
            "
          ></div>
          <div
            class="carousel-item"
            style="
              background-image: url(https://www.jqueryscript.net/dummy/8.jpg);
              position: fixed;
            "
          ></div>
          <div
            class="carousel-item"
            style="
              background-image: url(https://www.jqueryscript.net/dummy/9.jpg);
            "
          ></div>
          <div
            class="carousel-item"
            style="
              background-image: url(https://www.jqueryscript.net/dummy/10.jpg);
            "
          ></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

style.css:

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(231, 0, 0, 0.901);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  animation: hide-scroll 5s backwards;
}

@keyframes hide-scroll {
  0% { overflow: hidden; }
  100% { overflow: auto; }
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.carousel-inner, .carousel, .carousel-item, .carousel-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.carousel-item-prev:not(.carousel-item-end), .active.carousel-item-start {
  transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
}

.carousel-item-next:not(.carousel-item-start), .active.carousel-item-end {
  transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
}

.img-style {
  width: 100%;
}

.img-style:hover {
  width: 100%;
}

.roll-in-blurred-right {
    -webkit-animation: roll-in-blurred-right 1s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.320, 1.275) both;
            animation: roll-in-blurred-right 1s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.320, 1.275) both;
}
/* ----------------------------------------------
 * Generated by Animista on 2022-2-15 0:50:8
 * Licensed under FreeBSD License.
 * See http://animista.net/license for more info. 
 * w: http://animista.net, t: @cssanimista
 * ----------------------------------------------
 * animation roll-in-blurred-right
 * ---------------------------------------------- */
 @-webkit-keyframes roll-in-blurred-right {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(1000px) rotate(720deg);
            transform: translateX(1000px) rotate(720deg);
    -webkit-filter: blur(50px);
            filter: blur(50px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0) rotate(0deg);
            transform: translateX(0) rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-filter: blur(0);
            filter: blur(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes roll-in-blurred-right {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(1000px) rotate(720deg);
            transform: translateX(1000px) rotate(720deg);
    -webkit-filter: blur(50px);
            filter: blur(50px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0) rotate(0deg);
            transform: translateX(0) rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-filter: blur(0);
            filter: blur(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

index.js:

```
$("#vertical-carousel").bind("mousewheel DOMMouseScroll", function (e) {
  if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 || e.originalEvent.detail < 0) {
    $(this).carousel("prev");
  } else {
    $(this).carousel("next");
  }
  e.preventDefault();
});

$("#vertical-carousel").on("touchstart", function (event) {
  var yTouchPointStart = event.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY;
  $(this).on("touchmove", function (event) {
    var yTouchPointEnd = event.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY;
    if (Math.floor(yTouchPointStart - yTouchPointEnd) > 1) {
      $(".carousel").carousel("next");
    } else if (Math.floor(yTouchPointStart - yTouchPointEnd) < -1) {
      $(".carousel").carousel("prev");
    }
  });
  $(".carousel").on("touchend", function () {
    $(this).off("touchmove");
  });
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it:

Change the css `.carousel-item-prev:not` code like below:

```
.carousel-item-prev:not(.carousel-item-end), .active.carousel-item-start {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0%, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0%, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0%, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0%, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0%, 0);
}
```